# Installing Gitorious - rake gems:install aborted

Tags: rake, gitorious

following instructions for [installing Gitorious on RHEL](http://gitorious.org/gitorious/pages/Rhel_Installation)

When trying to run rake gems:install I get the following trace:

```
gitorious]$ sudo /opt/ruby-enterprise/bin/rake gems:install --trace
(in /var/www/html/gitorious)
rake aborted!
Bundler couldn't find some gems. Did you run `bundle install`?
/var/www/html/gitorious/config/../config/preinitializer.rb:18
/var/www/html/gitorious/config/boot.rb:28:in `load'
/var/www/html/gitorious/config/boot.rb:28:in `preinitialize'
/var/www/html/gitorious/config/boot.rb:10:in `boot!'
/var/www/html/gitorious/config/boot.rb:123
/opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
/opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/var/www/html/gitorious/Rakefile:4
/opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `load'
/opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2017:in `load_rakefile'
/opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2016:in `load_rakefile'
/opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2000:in `run'
/opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/opt/ruby-enterprise/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/opt/ruby-enterprise/bin/rake:19
```

I saw that you needed to put the gitorious.yml config directives under 'production:'. Not sure what to do next. I'm not a rubyist.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sam,
The problem here seems to be that the RHEL guide is outdated. Gitorious has moved to using Bundler for its Ruby dependencies, which actually makes things a lot simpler. What you should do is:

- Install the bundler gem (gem install bundler)
- Go into the Gitorious root and run bundle install

This should fix all Ruby dependencies. There's some more information about this change [in the blog](http://blog.gitorious.org/2011/02/17/gitorious-moves-gem-management-to-bundler/).

Comment: Ok, awesome. I will have to follow the install guide listed in the post.